# RAILS3: Full-text Search Word Docs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ms-word, full-text-search, documents

My company has a collection of about 3500 highly-structured Word docs (and growing) that contain multiple choice questions from one of our products. I've been tasked with writing a front-end that will let people find and use these in other products. There is some metadata on them that would go in a database, but we'd also like full-text search.

I've been given the option of using for the front-end either MS Access (because I know it well) or Rails (because I'm supposed to be learning it). I've done one Rails app and prefer to continue with it.

Rather than load the documents *into* the database, I thought it made more sense to just have them on the file system and store paths to them in the database.

I know I can use Ferret to search database fields but what's the best way to add full-text searching to a Rails app for a pile of files on the filesystem?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there are any gems that would search the word files for you. Although you have mentioned that you do not want to load the entire documents into the database, you might look into just copying the text contents of each file in your db. You can use win32ol library for doing this (http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/win32ole/rdoc/classes/WIN32OLE.html) .. If I had to implement this, I would run a cron job every night (or whatever frequency seems fit) that would refresh the database content with the changes in the word files.

Comment: Thanks for answering, Aniket!

I guess I was really thinking more along the lines of a good search engine that would index the files and then interact with the index in my Rails app to find and display hits. We're having a meeting soon to hash out the best way to do this so everything's up in the air at this point. I may end up putting the content in DB fields.